# How to do loops through XML in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

My XML looks like this :

```
<root>
  <row>
    <grade>A</grade>
    <Employee>
      <Name>ROBERT SUKIMIN</Name>
      <company>ABC</company>     
    </Employee>
    <Group>117761020</Group>
    <Designation>2014-03-21</Designation>
    <Company_code>5813044</Company_code>
  </row>
  <row>
    <grade>B</grade>
    <Employee>
      <Name>CECIL PAINEM</Name>
      <company>XYZ</company>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
      <Name>SUGRIWO</Name>
      <company>BCA</company>
    </Employee>
    <Group>40560050</Group>
    <Designation>2012-05-03</Designation>
    <Company_code>0</Company_code>
  </row>
</root>
```

I would like output:

```
A Robert Sukimin ABC 117761020 2014-03-21 5813044
B CECIL PAINEM XYZ 405600 2012-05-03 0
B SUGRIWO BCA 405600 2012-05-03 0
```

How loop in that xml and insert data into oracle table with minimal performance issue, assuming the 1000 record?

Comment: Why PL/SQL? Why not plain SQL?

Comment: Could you post what you have coded and describe what is wrong?

Comment: @AlexPoole and OP, why SQL? Any general purpose language (Java, C#, PHP, Python, VB) can parse XML documents and call other special purpose code like XPath and XSLT. As much as we love it, at the end of the day, SQL is a special-purpose language. Off to find the poster attempting to send an email with a stored proc (gasp) (sigh)!

Comment: @Parfait - sure, but if the XML is already in the DB, why pull it out to another layer when there are local tools to do the job?

Comment: @AlexPoole - sure, but arguably parsing XML is an application layer task. G/p languages can easily connect to most DBs and retrieve needed data. All depends on end-to-end need. I understand RDMS's have come a long way from just storing data points and blobs but for nuanced items, I would seek g/p modules. But to each his own!

Comment: Hi, have you tried **DBMS_XMLDOM** Package? it will do the job, look at this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644941/creating-xml-with-pl-sql/41647815#41647815

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple XMLTable levels to do this. One XMLTable gets the grade, group, designation etc. and also the current row as XMLType object. The second XMLTable then extracts all of the employee names from that extracted row.

With a CTE just to generate your base XML:

```
with t (xml) as (
  select xmltype('<root>
  <row>
    <grade>A</grade>
    <Employee>
      <Name>ROBERT SUKIMIN</Name>
      <company>ABC</company>     
    </Employee>
    <Group>117761020</Group>
    <Designation>2014-03-21</Designation>
    <Company_code>5813044</Company_code>
  </row>
  <row>
    <grade>B</grade>
    <Employee>
      <Name>CECIL PAINEM</Name>
      <company>XYZ</company>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
      <Name>SUGRIWO</Name>
      <company>BCA</company>
    </Employee>
    <Group>40560050</Group>
    <Designation>2012-05-03</Designation>
    <Company_code>0</Company_code>
  </row>
</root>') from dual
)
select x.grade, y.name, y.company, x.group_num, x.designation, x.company_code
from t
cross join xmltable ('/root/row'
  passing t.xml
  columns grade varchar2(1) path 'grade',
    row_xml xmltype path '.',
    group_num number path 'Group',
    designation varchar2(10) path 'Designation',
    company_code number path 'Company_code'
) x
cross join xmltable ('/row/Employee'
  passing x.row_xml
  columns name varchar2(30) path 'Name',
    company varchar2(5) path 'company'
) y;
```

which gets:

```
G NAME                           COMPA  GROUP_NUM DESIGNATIO COMPANY_CODE
- ------------------------------ ----- ---------- ---------- ------------
A ROBERT SUKIMIN                 ABC    117761020 2014-03-21      5813044
B CECIL PAINEM                   XYZ     40560050 2012-05-03            0
B SUGRIWO                        BCA     40560050 2012-05-03            0
```

You can insert the result of that query into another table with `insert into some_table (column1, column2, ...) select ...`.

In general you don't need PL/SQL to achieve this if the value is coming from a table.

If you have your XML in a PL/SQL variable, e.g. from your web service call, you can do the same thing using that variable instead of selecting directly from a table. You can still insert directly into your target table. In this example I've assumed your local PL/SQL variable with the web service result is called `l_xml` and is of type XMLType; and invented the table and column names so you'd obviously use your own real ones:

```
declare
  l_xml XMLType;
  ...
begin
  -- call web service to populate l_xml
  ...

  insert into you_table(grade, name, company, group_num, designation, company_code)
  select x.grade, y.name, y.company, x.group_num, x.designation, x.company_code
  from xmltable ('/root/row'
    passing l_xml    -- your local XMLType variable
    columns grade varchar2(1) path 'grade',
      row_xml xmltype path '.',
      group_num number path 'Group',
      designation varchar2(10) path 'Designation',
      company_code number path 'Company_code'
  ) x
  cross join xmltable ('/row/Employee'
    passing x.row_xml
    columns name varchar2(30) path 'Name',
      company varchar2(5) path 'company'
  ) y;

  ...
end;
```

If you're retrieving the web service result into a CLOB you can convert it as part of the call:

```
  ...
  from xmltable ('/root/row'
    passing XMLType(l_clob)    -- your local CLOB variable
  ...
```

You don't need to use any loops. You *could* use a cursor loop over that same query and insert each result into your table one by one, but that would just slow it down for no benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the case is how the loop in that xml and insert data into oracle table with minimal performance issue, assuming the 1000 record?

Comment: @user2728057 - you can simply insert the result of that query into a table. Why do you want to use loops, which would be less efficient than a simple `insert ... select`? Where are the 1000 XML records coming from, another table, a file....?

Comment: I call a webservice from my stored procedure and get an XML response. I want to parse the XML and insert the values into oracle table.

Comment: @user2728057 - I said you could do the same thing with a local PL/SQL variable. I've added an example to my answer, including inserting the result into a table - in one hit, no loops required.